# How to combine dictionaries that have the same element inside a list?

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, list, data-dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries. Some dictionaries share the same elements.

```
data = [
                 {'New_PCP_Name': 'Jack0',
                  'Member_Name': 'Jack0, 0',
                  'Member_ID': '111',
                  'DOB': '111',
                  'PCP_ID':'111'
                  },
                 {'New_PCP_Name': 'Jack0',
                  'Member_Name': 'Jack00, 00',
                  'Member_ID': '222',
                  'DOB': '222',
                  'PCP_ID':'111'
                  },
                    {'New_PCP_Name': 'Jack1',
                     'Member_Name': 'Jack1, 1',
                     'Member_ID': '333',
                     'DOB': '333',
                     'PCP_ID':'333'
                     },
                    {'New_PCP_Name': 'Jack2',
                     'Member_Name': 'Jack2, 2',
                     'Member_ID': '444',
                     'DOB': '444',
                     'PCP_ID':'444'
                     }
                 ]
```

I need to combine them in a specific format. The first 2 dicts share the same element 'New_PCP_Name': 'Jack0'. So I want to combine them. The final product is as below. This format has to be exactly like this because I need to use this format in a mail merge from the data imported from Excel.

```
data = [
                 {'New_PCP_Name': 'Jack0',
                  'PCP_ID':'111',
                  'Member_Name':[{'Member_Name':'Jack0, 0','Member_ID':'111','DOB':'111'},
                               {'Member_Name': 'Jack00, 00', 'Member_ID': '222', 'DOB': '222'}] 
                  },
                    {'New_PCP_Name': 'Jack1',
                     'Member_Name': 'Jack1, 1',
                     'Member_ID': '333',
                     'DOB': '333',
                     'PCP_ID':'333'
                     },
                    {'New_PCP_Name': 'Jack2',
                     'Member_Name': 'Jack2, 2',
                     'Member_ID': '444',
                     'DOB': '444',
                     'PCP_ID':'444'
                     }
                 ]
```

I'm new in python.I have tried breaking up the list, modifying the dictionaries and putting them back together as below. That didn't work out. Please help me figure out how to reformat the list of dicts. Or is there a way to import data from Excel in that specific format for the rows that share the same cell values?

```
data2=[]
for x in range (0,len(data),1):
    print(x)
    print(data[x])
    a = data[x]
    print(a['New_PCP_Name'])
    if x+1<=len(data):
        if data[x]['New_PCP_Name'] == data[x+1]['New_PCP_Name']:
            print('yes')
            data2.append(data[x])
        else:
            print('no')

print('data2=', data2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility is using `itertools.groupby` ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)):

```
data = [
                 {'New_PCP_Name': 'Jack0',
                  'Member_Name': 'Jack0, 0',
                  'Member_ID': '111',
                  'DOB': '111',
                  'PCP_ID':'111'
                  },
                 {'New_PCP_Name': 'Jack0',
                  'Member_Name': 'Jack00, 00',
                  'Member_ID': '222',
                  'DOB': '222',
                  'PCP_ID':'111'
                  },
                    {'New_PCP_Name': 'Jack1',
                     'Member_Name': 'Jack1, 1',
                     'Member_ID': '333',
                     'DOB': '333',
                     'PCP_ID':'333'
                     },
                    {'New_PCP_Name': 'Jack2',
                     'Member_Name': 'Jack2, 2',
                     'Member_ID': '444',
                     'DOB': '444',
                     'PCP_ID':'444'
                     }
                 ]

from itertools import groupby

out = []
for v, g in groupby(sorted(data, key=lambda k: k['New_PCP_Name']), lambda k: (k['New_PCP_Name'], k['PCP_ID'])):
    l = [*g]
    if len(l) == 1:
        out.append(l[0])
    else:
        pcp_id = None
        for i in l:
            del i['New_PCP_Name']
            del i['PCP_ID']
        out.append({'New_PCP_Name': v[0],
                    'PCP_ID': v[1],
                  'Member_Name':l
                  })

from pprint import pprint
pprint(out)
```

Prints:

```
[{'Member_Name': [{'DOB': '111', 'Member_ID': '111', 'Member_Name': 'Jack0, 0'},
                  {'DOB': '222',
                   'Member_ID': '222',
                   'Member_Name': 'Jack00, 00'}],
  'New_PCP_Name': 'Jack0',
  'PCP_ID': '111'},
 {'DOB': '333',
  'Member_ID': '333',
  'Member_Name': 'Jack1, 1',
  'New_PCP_Name': 'Jack1',
  'PCP_ID': '333'},
 {'DOB': '444',
  'Member_ID': '444',
  'Member_Name': 'Jack2, 2',
  'New_PCP_Name': 'Jack2',
  'PCP_ID': '444'}]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. However, I discover I need to bring out another field besides 'New_PCP_Name'. Let's say in the original data, I have an extra field PCP_ID that needs to be on the same level as 'New_PCP_Name' in the result. How would I go about that?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```py
new_data_dic = {}
for e in data:
    new_name = e['New_PCP_Name']
    if new_name not in new_data_dic:
        new_data_dic[new_name] = e.copy()
    else:
        if type(new_data_dic[new_name]['Member_Name'] == str):
            inner = new_data_dic[new_name].copy()
            del inner['New_PCP_Name']
            del new_data_dic[new_name]['Member_ID']
            del new_data_dic[new_name]['DOB']
            new_data_dic[new_name]['Member_Name'] = [inner]
        inner = e.copy()
        del inner['New_PCP_Name']
        new_data_dic[new_name]['Member_Name'].append(inner)
data2 = list(new_data_dic.values())
```

Explained: The `'New_PCP_Name'` is a key, so I create a dictionary. I transform `'Member_Name'` to a list in case I see another occurence of the same key. On subsequent appearances I can append.

Comment: Thank you. However, there are 2 extra elements at the end of the first dict in the result: 
````data2 = [{'New_PCP_Name': 'Jack0', 'Member_Name': [{'Member_Name': 'Jack0, 0', 'Member_ID': '111', 'DOB': '111'},
                                                   {'Member_Name': 'Jack00, 00', 'Member_ID': '222', 'DOB': '222'}],````

          **'Member_ID': '111', 'DOB': '111'}**,

         {'New_PCP_Name': 'Jack1', 'Member_Name': 'Jack1, 1', 'Member_ID': '333', 'DOB': '333'},

         {'New_PCP_Name': 'Jack2', 'Member_Name': 'Jack2, 2', 'Member_ID': '444', 'DOB': '444'}]````

Comment: You can just delete those fields with `del`. I have updated the answer and added two new lines which remove those fields.